# ebean with db2 transaction isolation=none ignored

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, ebean

ebean overrides transaction isolation=none in the connection string and uses some level of transaction isolation. This is resulting in `java.sql.SQLException: [SQL7008]`. For reasons out of my control the table has no journal. I have been unsuccessful finding information on no transaction isolation.

This is the faulty line:

```
Ebean.createSqlUpdate("UPDATE dummytable SET column1 = 'Test' WHERE id = 1").execute();
```

This is the connection string:

```
datasource.as400.databaseUrl=jdbc:as400://localhost/LIBRARY;naming=sql;errors=full;transaction isolation=none;
```

Comment: Try `UPDATE dummytable SET column1 = 'Test' WHERE id = 1 WITH NC`, But won't ebean be lost after any rollback ?

Comment: By trial and error, I stumbled upon `datasource.as400.isolationlevel=none`. Although I am not able to find any documentation for it.